# GitHub context not getting labels because it's "not a pull request". How can I debug this?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repo I'm adding to. It's integrated with GitHub Actions. I am trying to retrieve labels associated with PRs, in order for the script to run the correct jobs. I have the jobs working, but am just trying to perform the label check. I was using the following to get the label:

```
- name: Check for labels
        
id: label-check

run: | echo "newFeature=${{ contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'newFeature') }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I was getting `echo "newFeature=false"` and decided to log the `github.event.pull_request.labels` but it came back null. after digging deep enough, I got a log that the context `github` has no `pull_request` event, and a different logger stated "Not a pull request". I'm not sure if it's just the access from the workflow, or it's technically not a PR by GitHub's standards. Are there any suggestions to how I could debug this?

Was expecting:
echo "newFeature=true"

Comment: You have to show more of your workflow, specifically the trigger (the `on:` value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you cannot do much to debug this issue other than going through the documentation.

This is Github's Documentation:

> [The `github.event`] object is identical to the webhook payload of the event that triggered the workflow run, and is different for each event.
> [source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context)

So if you're trying to use `github.event.something`, double-check your job trigger is using `something` as the Webhook event payload. In your case, `github.event.pull_request` is set with [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) and [pull request target](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) triggers.

Most likely, you need to fix your trigger. Try with:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
```

One last thing to keep in mind, you might want to update the `types` to trigger the workflow when a label is added or removed. See the example below:

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, labeled, unlabeled] # note I'm adding labeled & unlabeled here

jobs:
  check-pr-labels:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Show PR labels
        run: |
          echo "PR Labels"
          echo "PR_LABELS_JSON=${PR_LABELS_JSON}"
        env:
          PR_LABELS_JSON: ${{ toJson(github.event.pull_request.labels) }}
      - name: Has Label "demo"
        run: |
          echo "Has label 'demo'"
          echo "HAS_LABEL=${HAS_LABEL}"
        env:
          HAS_LABEL: ${{ contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'demo') }} # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-using-an-object-filter
```

A note: You don't have to here, but I'm using an `env` instead of templating the script, out of habit. Check ["security hardening"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#good-practices-for-mitigating-script-injection-attacks) to learn more about why you might want to get into this habit too.

Comment: Thank you! big help and much appreciated. this helped me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can specify the pull request action in the github actions and you have another option also for this to work. I will specify both of them below:

**Method 1:**
You can just simply specify pull request even within the brackets in the on field.

```
name: checking labels in pull request
on: [pull_request]
```

**Method 2:**
Since you want to check the labels on your pull request you can use the labeled event to trigger this check.

```
name: checking labels in pull request
on:  
  pull_request:
     types: [labeled,unlabeled]
```